# No Customise option for Google Analytics Dashboards coming from Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

According to Google's documentation:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1068218?hl=en

I can create customised dashboards in the Google Analytics home page by using the left panel menu.

However I cannot find this button for a project that I have imported from Firebase.
Is there really no way to have custom dashboards for such imported projects?

Is my only alternative to start over with a new Google Analytics project?

Or can do something from the Firebase side?